# Stratifying Interaction in R

Tags: subset, linear-regression, logistic-regression, interaction

**I have been putting in these codes:**
race_caucasian <- lm(ds$BMI~ds$User+ds$Age+ds$Female+ds$Insurance+ds$Income+ds$Vaccine+ds$Nonsmoker,data=subset(phrnew,Caucasian=="1"))

And

> race_other <- lm(ds$BMI~ds$User+ds$Age+ds$Female+ds$Insurance+ds$Income+ds$Vaccine+ds$Nonsmoker,data=subset(phrnew,Caucasian=="0"))

And I am getting the exact same output. I have subsets in the code but i don't think they are computing

Help please

Comment: You are doing regression from the data frame `ds`, and not from your input data frame `subset(phrne..`

Comment: it should be `lm(BMI~User + Age + .., data = subset(phrne...))`

Comment: How to I input the dataset in so that I dont have to do  they "ds$" before the characters?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.